# After 'pod update' two unknown dependencies will be installed

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

After `pod update` two unknown dependencies

```
FirebaseAnalytics (3.2.0)
FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.6)
```

will be automatically installed, even they (whatever `Firebase` or `FirebaseAnalytics` or `FirebaseInstanceID` ) aren't in the Podfile.

But if use `pod install` then no problem, this two won't be installed.

Cocoapods version: 0.39.0 and 1.0.0 (I have tried it unter the two versions)

xcode: 7.3

Anyone knows reason?

thanks!

[image: The Podfile]

## [image: After pod update]

ps. yes, I did in the Podfile once

```
pod 'Firebase', '<=2.5.1'
```

but it made other problems, i.e another pod dependence `TAGContainer.h` cannot be found anymore, so I've already deleted `Firebase` from the Podfile and the problem ist still there.

Comment: can you show your Podfile ? Also could you please provide more details about your environment ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unaware, Firebase recently updated their sdk (and it was a pretty big update). You might have something like this in your podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase'
```

If you want to continue using the old version of Firebase you'll need to makes sure that pod doesn't get updated. So make sure that pod is restricted to a specific pod version (like this):

```
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'
```

(I got that line [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html) btw)

If you DO want to update to the latest version of the SDK (which is always recommended) 
Check out this link to migrate: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios

My personal podfile got converted from the pod line above to:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
```

As described in the firebase docs - They separated out the different Firebase features into separate Cocoapods, so you'll need to import them individually. You might not need all these features like I did, but you get the picture.

You posted your podfile I, or someone else, could probably be more helpful

Comment: I've already tried `pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'`. After`pod install` the header file  cannot be found in the project, it means I cannot `import Firebase`. If `pod update`, I can `import Firebase` but there are other problems, i.e `TAGContainer.h` cannot be found anymore.

Comment: Sorry @shilei365 you'll have to be more specific. Already tried updating your podfile to `pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'`? Already tried updating to the latest sdk?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and scrolled back through my command line history. The TAGContainer.h along with TAGContainerOpener.h, TAGDataLayer.h, TAGLogger.h, and TAGManager.h have been deleted when I updated my GoogleTagManager pod from 3.15.0 to 5.0.6. That's mostly likely what happened to you. It's not necessarily coming from updating Firebase.

I'll update my answer when I find a solution.